# How to implement spring Pre-Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

My application currently is authenticated using Java EE container security. It has a login.jsp which submits the login form to j_security_check and authenticates.

I need to implement Spring Security in my application keeping the login as it is. I think we can do it using spring Pre-Authentication, but I have no idea what the steps are to implement this.

Can someone help me to get a start on this?

Comment: Did you configured the spring security in your application ? For applying spring security, explain what you have done so far and where are is the issue ? Do you have trouble in just in using the custom login page ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security has an other feature: it can protect urls (like a severlet container security). This is much easyer way to start.

The Spring Security Web Page itself contains a page:  [Suggested Steps for Getting Started with Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html) - I strongly recommend the first steps, including the [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html).

If you need more detailed information then the very good [Spring Security Book](http://www.packtpub.com/spring-security-3-1/book) is the best way (in my opinion).

---

If you already have a spring application with spring security form based login and protected urls configured, then enabling `@Pre-Authentication` support is just enabling "[Method Security Expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)" configuration.

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is explained to implement spring security in the below link.

[Step By Step.](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html)